# How to extract the data from a kafka inbound message with spring

Tags: spring-integration, apache-kafka

I am building a Kafka consumer with spring. My configuration seems to be pretty straightforward. Messages are being consumed and saved in files. However, the payload is cryptic and I can't get the data (short "hello world" messages).

This is what I get when I access the payload (e.g. when I set up a transformer bean btween in inbound kafka and the outboud file:

```
{test-topic={0=[[B@713c9d72, [B@7d656f90, [B@26bb8c83, [B@4b959d83 [B@5ed74e8e]}}
```

My question is: How do I access the actual payload (the "hellow world" string")?

My configuration is :

```
<int:channel id="inputFromKafka">
    <int:queue />
</int:channel>
        <int:poller 
        max-messages-per-poll="5" default = "true" fixed-delay="10" time-unit="MILLISECONDS"/>

<int-kafka:inbound-channel-adapter
    id="kafkaInboundChannelAdapter" kafka-consumer-context-ref="consumerContext"
    auto-startup="true" channel="inputFromKafka">

<int-kafka:consumer-context id="consumerContext"
    consumer-timeout="40000" zookeeper-connect="zookeeperConnect">
    <int-kafka:consumer-configurations>
        <int-kafka:consumer-configuration
            group-id="group12" max-messages="5">
            <int-kafka:topic id="test-topic" streams="1" />
        </int-kafka:consumer-configuration>
    </int-kafka:consumer-configurations>
</int-kafka:consumer-context>
<int-kafka:zookeeper-connect id="zookeeperConnect"
    zk-connect="localhost:2181" zk-connection-timeout="6000"
    zk-session-timeout="6000" zk-sync-time="2000" />


<file:outbound-channel-adapter id="filesOut"
    directory="/tmp/fromKafka">
    </file:outbound-channel-adapter>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are seeing raw `byte[]`.

Add...

```
<bean id="decoder" 
    class="org.springframework.integration.kafka.serializer.common.StringDecoder" />
```

and

```
<int-kafka:consumer-configuration
                     value-decoder="decoder"
        ...
```